# What's stored queries in Lotus Notes?

Tags: lotus-notes

Using Design Synopsis, I found 'Stored Queries' element type but I can not find any ways to view, edit or delete these 'stored queries'. What's it? How to take control of this type of design element?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Stored Queries are saved view searches. You can see this in action by opening a view in the database, and then perform a view search. The search bar should appear allowing you to type in a search.

You should be able to select a "More" twistie on the right, the View search bar should expand down, presenting a few more options. There you'll see a number of parameters and filters for searching. There should also be 2 buttons "Save Search" and "Load Search". This is what design synopsis is referring to, the saved searches for views, but they're called "Stored Queries" by design synopsis. Selecting "Load Search" should also give you the option to "Delete Saved Search".

[Here](http://www-12.lotus.com/ldd/doc/domino_notes/rnext/help6_client.nsf/f4b82fbb75e942a6852566ac0037f284/d9306d177a6e63ef85256c1c00380035?OpenDocument) is some doco on how to use it. The instructions are compatible from R6.5 thru to 8.5.